# Change boot display in a modern laptop

Tags: laptop, uefi, laptop-display

I have an ASUS UP5302 laptop. A while ago it stopped displaying the boot logo and the GRUB bootloader on its integrated display, even the BIOS setup and Windows don't use it. However, it does use an external display to show the boot logo and the BIOS setup. I tried the following:

- Scoured the BIOS setup for anything related with no luck
- Attached and detached external displays multiple times
- Closed, opened, flipped the screen in multiple ways while booted into the BIOS setup, Windows and Linux
- Did an EC reset by holding the power button for 40 seconds
- Disconnected the battery for a while
- Reset all options in the BIOS setup
- Did a BIOS upgrade
- Tried to adjust the brightness
- Tried to change display settings while booted
- Contacted support, who told me to bring the laptop in

Is there any straightforward fix that I missed? Probably the primary boot display was changed somehow and it would be fixed by changing it back, but I have no idea where to look. Strangely enough, SDDM and KDE can enable and use the integrated display, so if possible I would avoid sending the laptop in for a repair.

Comment: Does the BIOS not have some config option for Display, called something like "Boot Display Device"?

Comment: Nope. Only thing about display in the BIOS is the amount of RAM to preallocate for the internal graphics. I tried changing that too.

Comment: What happens when you disconnect all external monitors? What do you see in Device Manager under "Display adapters"?

Comment: Windows can't see the built-in display in device manager, can't display on it. When in Windows, there's no picture on the built-in display even if I disconnect everything else.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't see the integrated display adapter in Device Manager
under "Display adapters", this is probably a hardware problem.

I have no explanation as to why SDDM and KDE can enable and use the
integrated display adapter, but they don't use the same driver
and may use different hardware commands to detect its presence
than Windows.

If Windows is fully updated,
I don't think that you can avoid sending the laptop in for repair.
You have basically done everything possible.